anchor-lang and solana-client dependency conflict
I need the get_account method of solana-client, but they have conflicting dependencies
Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "token_claim"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "token_claim"

[features]
default = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []
idl-build = ["anchor-lang/idl-build", "anchor-spl/idl-build"]

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = { version = "0.30.1", features = ["init-if-needed"] }
anchor-spl = "0.30.1"
solana-client = "2.1.7"



Since anchor 0.30.1 uses v1.17 of the Solana crates, you'll likely have an easier time using the same version in your project, ie update your solana-client dependency to 1.17 or 1.18.

Hello, I originally wanted to generate AccountInfo through address for batch transfer of sol and token. In my attempts, solana-client and anchor-client seem unable to achieve this.

You should ask a new question with more information if you're running into other issues, since that's unrelated to the dependency conflict from your original question
